# How to save boolean in SharedPreferences and use it in android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I want check value with **boolean**, when **likeState** is `true`, show me true `toast` and when **likeState** is `false`, show me false `toast`.
in my application every user just can for one time click on like button. when click on button **likeState** is true and save true state for all.

I write below codes, but not work me and not save **state**!

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor stateEditor;
private boolean likeState = false, reportState;
private String stateLike_TAG = "LIKE_STATE";

statePrefs = getSharedPreferences(stateLike_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
stateEditor = statePrefs.edit();
// set Preferences
likeState = statePrefs.getBoolean(stateLike_TAG, false);

if (!likeState) {
    TastyToast.makeText(context, "Like, Thnx", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
    stateEditor.putBoolean("liked", true);
}
```

I want to use `sharedPreferences` to save the states, how can I do it?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `commit()`

Comment: i added `commit()` but not work me again

Comment: `stateLike_TAG  != "liked"`

Comment: @codeMagic, can you send me code? i am amateur. please my bro

Comment: `stateEditor.putBoolean(stateLike_TAG , true);`

Comment: @codeMagic, not work me again, why? :(

Comment: I don't know without seeing what code you have now. Have you done any debugging like breakpoints or logs to make sure where the code is going? Is there any error? What is/isn't happening?